# myVector class - erasing

Tags: c++

I need to put std::vector to template class. Everything works fine apart from erasing

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
template <class TBase> 
class TCollection
{
protected:
  //The Vector container that will hold the collection of Items
  vector<TBase> m_items;
public:
  int Add(void) 
  {
    //Create a new base item
    TBase BaseItem; 
    //Add the item to the container
    m_items.push_back(BaseItem); 
    //Return the position of the item within the container. 
    //Zero Based
    return (m_items.size()-1); 
  }
  //Function to return the memory address of a specific Item
  TBase* GetAddress(int ItemKey) 
  {
    return &(m_items[ItemKey]);
 }
  //Remove a specific Item from the collection
  void Remove(int ItemKey) 
  {
    //Remove the Item using the vector’s erase function
    m_items.erase(GetAddress(ItemKey)); 
  }
  void Clear(void) //Clear the collection
  {
    m_items.clear();
  }
  //Return the number of items in collection
  int Count(void) 
  {
    return m_items.size(); //One Based
  }
  //Operator Returning a reference to TBase
  TBase& operator [](int ItemKey) 
  {
    return m_items[ItemKey];
  }
};
```

I'm getting error:

> 1>b:\projects\c++\wolvesisland\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6\myvector.h(24): error C2664: 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec> std::vector<_Ty>::erase(std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'obiekt **' to 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>'

The way I'm trying to erase: data.Remove(2); where data is myVector < object > data;
App code is fine (I tested it using only std::vector without putting it to template). I would be thankful for your help.

Comment: Have a look at a [std::vector::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) reference.

Comment: The error tells you what's wrong, read it, then figure out how to turn the `ItemKey` index into the correct argument type (hint: it's not `GetAddress`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `erase` method only accepts iterators, it does not accept pointers as argument. Look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase).

A possible correction could be

```
std::vector<TBase>::const_iterator it = m_items.begin() + ItemKey;
m_items.erase(it);
```

though I didn't test it firsthand.

Answer (score 2):

vector erase function only accepts iterator.

```
vec.erase(vec.begin()+ItemKey);
```